# Without calculating the integral, prove that this is true

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to prove that this is true without calculating the integral?

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \frac{4}{3}\bigl(1 + x^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigr)^{\frac{3}{2}} + C$$

Comment: Well, what's the *defining property* of indefinite integrals...?

Comment: Are you allowed to compute the derivative of the right-hand side?

Comment: Computing integrals can seem like an NP problem--they can be hard to compute, but it's easy to verify that a solution is correct.  Your tool for verifying a solution is your best friend in calculus, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @user334137 FToC doesn’t say anything about indefinite integrals, but rather definite integrals. OP would want to use the definition of an indefinite integral in this case.

Comment: @Ducky It in fact gives you both http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely not difficult to prove it's true even with calculating the integral, because 
$$\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)'=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
thus
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\int \left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}} \right)d\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)=...$$
and substituting $y=1+\sqrt{x}$
$$...=2\int \sqrt{y} dy=\frac{4}{3}y^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$